# Onclick function of javascript for submit button not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit

I have checked the other same posts and I have done numerous changes but nothing seems to work! My goal is to create a form, in html, that when the user is submitting data having clicked on the plane or ship to redirect him in another form A and for the rest (train, bus) to the form B. For that I have the foo function in javascript. But when I click on submit button the onclick function does not work! Any ideas why?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> <title> Ticket Choice </title></HEAD> 
   <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    function foo(){
        alert("Submit button clicked!");
        if (document.getElementById('buttonCheck1') || 
(document.getElementById('buttonCheck2')) {
document.forms['form0'].action="C:/Users/Jo/workspace/myAskisisDir/WebContent/formA.html";
        }
        else {
            document.forms['form0'].action="C:/Users/Jo/workspace/myAskisisDir/WebContent/formB.html";

        }

    }
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<h1> Choice of transfer ticket </h1>
<FORM id = "form0"  method = "GET">
<fieldset title = "plane">
<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(1);" name = "button" id =
"buttonCheck1"> PLANE <br>
 </fieldset>
<fieldset title = "ship">
<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(2);" name = "button" id =
"buttonCheck2"> SHIP <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset title = "train">
<input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(3);" name = "button" id =
"buttonCheck3">train<br>
</fieldset>
 <fieldset title = "bus">
 <input type = "radio" onclick = "javascript:IsCheck(4);" name = "button" id =
"buttonCheck4"> bus <br>
    </fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick = "foo();"/>
<input type = "reset"/>
 </FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Don't use file system paths as urls. Use relative paths, or if you really have to use the file system (and if this will always be used only offline), use `file:///...`

Comment: Is the function not called or is there a javascript error in the function?

Comment: I think that it is not calling the function. It does not show the alert.I tried calling foo and in other places and I still have the same problem!

Comment: @Juhana : it is still work under process, I will replace them later with urls. I changed the file:/// though, thanks.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Thanks for that I did not know it existed, I had a missing parenthesis, now it enters in the function but it does not redirect me to the other forms...

Answer (score 0):

syntax error

`if (document.getElementById('buttonCheck1')||(document.getElementById('buttonCheck2')) {`

should have been

`if (document.getElementById('buttonCheck1') || document.getElementById('buttonCheck2')) {`

now you can feel stupid :P

Try it, this triggers the onclick function. Cheers!